# Determine whether the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!+n}{(n+2)!}$ is convergent or divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Determine whether the series
>   $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!+n}{(n+2)!}$$
>   is convergent or divergent.

Wolfram Alpha says that "By the comparison test, the series converges" but I can't find any good possibilities for a bounding series.

Comment: Try the series with terms $2n!/(n+2)!$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_n \frac{n!+n}{(n+2)!} = \sum_n \frac{n!}{(n+2)!} + \sum_n \frac{n}{(n+2)!}  \leq \sum_n \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \sum_n \frac{n+2}{(n+2)!}$$
and the two series converge.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the sum, after say, $n = 20$,  with $\sum \frac{20}{n^2}$. Better still, note that it's less than
$$
\sum \frac{n! + n!}{(n+2)!}
$$
and compare it to $\sum \frac{2}{n^2}$.